# Ubuntu 18.04 Crashes when watching videos

Tags: video, laptop

No matter where I am watching a video, it seems to crash my laptop. I'm using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 on [this laptop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077GN5H7D) . I tried youtube, netflix, hulu, and popcorn-time but it just crashes. Ill start the video and it plays it for a little while, but then the audio just repeats over and over again. When this happens, I have to restart my computer to fix it. If you have any questions, just ask. Thanks.

Comment: This is a hardware problem related to the graphics processor which for your laptop is Intel HD Graphics 620. It could be caused by dust blocking the air flow around the aluminum CPU cooling fins.

Comment: This issue is affecting my laptop since upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04.